# Removing (unset) all cookies that are older that were created before today & making a subdirectory keep in browser history?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, cookies

I'm trying to remove all cookies from my website that were created before today... so that anyone who's a returning to the site will lose all of their old cookies and will get a fresh set of cookies.

I can't use `RequestHeader unset Cookie` because it will just keep removing cookies until I remove it, I want it so it removes all cookies made before 07/01/2015

I'm also trying to "fix" my site so that browsers remember the directory /f1fol/ because for some reason no browser remembers that page (not sure what's causing the problem)

Anyone know how to do this/what's the problem?

Comment: impossible: you cannot tell when a cookie was created, only when it expires.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by `so that browsers remember the directory /f1fol/`?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I have a page that is domain.com/f1fol and for some reason no browsers (regardless of who/where/what browser/what device) remember the link... it never stores it in browser auto-fill... example: http://i.imgur.com/8PHiZXf.png

Comment: You are most probably redirecting the directory to some other URL immediately. Most browsers would simply ignore storing it so as not to annoy the users with a back-forward history loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the thing: a browser never reports the creation date of a cookie. When a cookie is created, only the expiration date the server specified during its creation is stored along with its value, and hence, only that gets reported back to the server until the day the cookie crumbles/expires.

But, the end effect which you want, that anyone who's returning to the site should lose all of their old cookies and get a fresh new set is possible to achieve. Add the following code to a PHP include file named, say, ***purge_old_cookies.php***

```
<?
// Check if this script has run before
if (!isset($_COOKIE['purged_once'])) {

  // Check for old cookies
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {

    $cookies = explode(";", $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);

    // Iterate and unset all cookies
    foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {

      $fields = explode("=", $cookie);
      $name = trim(fields[0]);

      // unset any cookie for the current path
      setcookie($name, "", time() - 3600);

      // unset the cookie for the root path
      setcookie($name, "", time() - 3600, "/");
    }
  }

  // Set a purged marker for the current path
  setcookie("purged_once", "1", strtotime("+6 months"));
}
?>
```

A cookie is forced to expire by setting its expiration date in the past. The code above sets it to yesterday.

Notice, the `setcookie()` method is fired twice as the cookies must be deleted with the same parameters as they were set with. The above would suffice in most cases but if your site had set cookies with different `domain`, `secure` or `httponly` parameters, you may have to pass them as well.

Once the above script is ready, just include it at the beginning of all the required pages.

```
<?
  include '/path/to/purge_old_cookies.php';
  ...
?>
```

If you're sure that your site never set a cookie for a specific `/dir/path` i.e. always passed a `path` value of `/`, then you can unset all the cookies by adding this script to just `/index.php`. The two `setcookie()` calls (with and without `/`) then effectively become the same and you can drop one. The `purged_once` cookie would also be set on root as

```
setcookie("purged_once", "1", strtotime("+6 months"), "/");
```

This would also restrict the marker cookies to just one per user.

#### Please Note:

> Keep the marker ***purged_once*** cookie **set to expire after a long time**
>   like 3 to 6 months. **If you keep it very low and forget to
>   remove the script, you'll end up purging all the new cookies** your site
>   sets from the time this script was introduced.

Comment: The domain was setup to allow both www and non-www addresses but recently it's been changed to force www addresses for seo purposes and compatibility purposes. Anyone anyone who logged in or did certain things with non-www addresses now have a lot of useless cookies as-well as an error in part of my website was issuing cookies without expiry dates and there are hundreds of bad cookies.

Comment: In that case, you would need two `setcookie()` calls; one with `domain` param as `.domain.com` and another with `www.domain.com`. Regarding expiry dates, you must have set some time because cookies don't persist otherwise. If the time is set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire when the user exits the browser.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong but the code doesn't seem to be working, for example if I put this at the start of a php file none of the php works...

Comment: Create a test.php file that includes this script followed by simple echo statements. If the echos print, the script is fine. Check if the opening `if` block is being closed properly or not.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/main/test.php on line 14` which is `$name = trim(fields[0]);`

Comment: It needs a `$` prefix just before the variable name like `$fields[0]`.

Comment: Ahh my bad, yeah that worked however the code seems to be forcefully removing cookies continuously ignoring the 6 month thing.

Comment: Check the browser if "purged_once" cookie is being set or not. The first `if` condition excludes the whole script if it's set. If it's not being set please share the complete script you're using by updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function, you can set the time the cookie expires. If you want it to expire today, you can try something like that:

```
setcookie('var', 'value', strtotime(date('Y-m-d 23:59:59'));
```

and this will make it to expire in the last second of the current day. You can check cookie existence like that:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['var'])) {
   //do something with it
} else {
   //store cookie var and do something else
}
```

If you need to store a directory path for a longer time, you can set expiry time to a far future date.

Comment: I want all cookies to be reset/removed/expired though and how would I incorporate that into sites like wordpress, joomla... etc as a once include?

Answer (score 0):

May be from PHP, you can also change the life span of a cookie from javascript as well. You can simply read the cookie and if date is less than your desired time delete the cookie .[more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)